# Ceiling function in Access

Tags: excel, ms-access, math, vba, ms-office

How to create a Ceiling Function in MS access that behaves the same as the one in Excel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a Reference to the Microsoft Excel Object Library and use `Excel.WorksheetFunction.Ceiling`

Comment: Do I have to make a VBA function that wraps the call to Excel.WorksheetFunction.Ceiling() or can I use that in an expression?

Comment: You can use it directly in VBA but need to create a wrapper to use the function in a Access Form.

Comment: This is a very slow method. See answer from MiloNC how to do this in Access.

Answer (score 22):

Since Int() seems to work like Floor(), you can get Ceiling like this:
    -Int(-x)

Comment: This is such a beautiful, simple solution. I think I would create a function like Arthur did so it's clear in the code what is happening.

Answer (score 9):

This answer uses VBA for Access, and is derived from http://www.tek-tips.com/faqs.cfm?fid=5031:

```
Public Function Ceiling(ByVal X As Double, Optional ByVal Factor As Double = 1) As Double
    ' X is the value you want to round
    ' Factor is the optional multiple to which you want to round, defaulting to 1
    Ceiling = (Int(X / Factor) - (X / Factor - Int(X / Factor) > 0)) * Factor
End Function
```

Note that this answer is mathematically correct for negative X. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions#Spreadsheet_software for background.

Comment: I would strongly recommend breaking this down into multiple steps, storing the result of each sub-calculation in a variable with known precision in order to minimize the effects of floating point imprecision.

Comment: This function doesn't use anything in the Access object model, so why call it _VBA for Access_?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks, marg, for the answer. For future reference, here is the VBA function that I wrote after importing the Microsoft Excel Object Library:

```
Public Function Ceiling(Value As Double, Significance As Double) As Double
    Ceiling = Excel.WorksheetFunction.Ceiling(Value, Significance)
End Function
```

Then in my query, I was trying to calculate billable hours from actual time worked, rounding up to the next quarter hour:

```
SELECT Ceiling(([WorkTimes]![EndTime]-[WorkTimes]![BeginTime])*24,0.25) AS BillableTime
FROM WorkTimes;
```

Comment: I know this comment is 10 years old, but I think it worth adding that this solution implicitly instantiates an Excel Application object every time it's called, which adds significant overhead. Better to declare a module-level or static variable to instantiate once with code such as `static XLapp as Excel.Application: If XLapp is nothing then Set XLapp = new Excel.application` and change the calculation line to use XLapp.WorksheetFunction insead of Excel.WorksheetFunction

Comment: "I have no memory of this place…" - Gandalf

Answer (score -1):

While this question specifically asked for Access here is the answer for VB.NET

```
Public Function Ceiling(ByVal value As Double, ByVal factor As Double) As Double
    Return Math.Ceiling(value / factor) * factor
End Function
```

And the answer in C#

```
public double Ceiling(double value, double factor)
{
    return Math.Ceiling(value / factor) * factor;
}
```

I'm posting it here because I needed such a function google sent me to this question but I couldn't find an answer for .Net. I finally figured it out for myself.